# BB10 debugging and showing logs on Android Runtime

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I try to port my android app to BB10 platform. My development os is windows and blackberry plugin of eclipse gives some runtime errors. it seems that it is not stable yet. I just wonder that is there anyway to check logs without using eclipse plugin?

[Blackberry graphical aid tools](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Tablet-OS-Graphical-Aid/ta-p/1207067) can be used for compatibility check and signing apps but it doesn't show the logs.

Comment: Have you tried the command line tools?

Comment: i guess graphical aid tool is using command line tool in background.

Comment: Yes, but you have the control to do what you want with the command line tools. And it displays the error in the console (even if it's not always relevent).
And finally it also allow you to dig into the java code of the command line tool to really understand what's the problem. It has already helped me to know that the error was 'I couldn't sign twice the same version of a .bar'